# ContactForm7 - how to get ACTUAL error?

Tags: wordpress, debugging

Like a lot of people, I'm slowly ripping out my remaining hair trying to get the 'simple' ContactForm7 working on a WordPress site.
I'm faced with the oh-so-helpful "Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the administrator by another method." message.

So, having tried all the obvious things*, I really want to know WHY it's failing. WP-MAIL-SMTP returns the complete pass/fail message when doing a test, which was a great help to get the SMTP connection working.

Does anyone happen to know where in the ContactForm7 code I can temporarily put in an ECHO to display the failure message so that I can track down the problem? I'm sure this will be a MASSIVE help to everyone that's asking the same question over and over again.

Cheers!

[*] The obvious being:

- Make sure I have a valid email to send from
- Put in the Reply-To additional field
- Check that I can send emails using the "lost password" message. (mail works)
- Try sending by SMTP (Can send both php_mail and SMTP)
- SSL / AUTH setting, Port setting (see above)
- Turn off other plugins.